# Unable to show image on page returned by Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I need to show the image on my web page. I have given the url of the image as:

```
<img src="http://localhost:57401/assets/getimagebyid/?userId=22&imageId=2012" alt="Sample Image">
```

This is the API method to get the stream:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImageById(int userId, int imageId)
{
var objResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
var ImageStream = ImageStorage.DownloadImageStream(userId, imageId);

var resourceByteArray = new byte[ImageStream .Length];

var dataStream = new MemoryStream(resourceByteArray);
objResponse.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
objResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
objResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
return objResponse;
}
```

These are the response headers in the developer console:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 209855
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcaW5ldHB1Ylx3d3dyb290XFBob3RvQnV0bGVyXFBob3RvQnV0bGVyLkFQSVxhc3NldHNcZ2V0YXNzZXRzYnlpZFw=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 10:57:09 GMT
```

There is no error in the above code. Also, the status is 200(OK). Why the image is not showing on the web page? What am I missing?

Comment: You're essentially returning nothing... I think you meant to copy `ImageStream` to your `resourceByteArray` or set the content as `new StreamContent(ImageStream)`.

Comment: @CharlesMager Yes. You are right. I have found the solution. That was the hint.